# Translate "from fiction, truth" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to translate the following into Latin:

> "From fiction, truth"

The semantic suggestion is that truth is manufactured from fiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first phrase that comes to mind is "Veritas ex Fabula." If you're looking for a phrase more in the idiom of In Vino Veritas, you could switch the word order around: "Ex Fabula, Veritas." This is a literal transliteration of your English into Latin. For a more idiomatic sentence, searching Latin databases for set phrases could be frutiful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it idiomatic to remove the comma?

Comment: Ancient Latin did not use commas. As far as I know, they used very little punctuation so that there was more room to fit the letters on paper. The MOST idiomatic phrasing would probably be "VERITASEXFABULA" -- the Romans spelled using only capital letters, and no spaces. I would not recommend this phrasing -- I would use "Veritas ex Fabula"